# How can I group processes by application in htop?

Tags: linux, top, htop

In htop, how can I group processes by application? I've tried pressing `H`, but that doesn't seem to do the trick. Here is a good example of the problem I'm trying to solve:

[image]

In the above, I want to see total memory usage for all `gnome-shell` processes, and another line for all `chrome` processes.

Answer (score 3):

There's only one `gnome-shell` process in your screenshot – with a whole lot of *threads.* All threads share the same memory allocations (it's only 983M total, *not* 22×983M), so "grouping" them is the same as merely hiding them – pressing `H` (specifically <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>) will do exactly that.

`chrome` is a more complex situation, as it has several separate child processes, *each* of which has its own threads. (There are two `chrome` processes in your screenshot.) Again, you should start by hiding the threads and leaving only the processes to get more sensible numbers.

Unfortunately htop doesn't support grouping processes any further (neither by program name nor by parent relationships), so there's nothing much you can do – you could enable tree mode with `t` and collapse children with `-`, but that's not very useful because htop won't sum the memory usage of child processes.

Instead, as long as you're using GNOME, you could try `systemd-cgtop` which groups processes by *cgroup* – GNOME will start each app in its own cgroup (see systemd-cgls), so you should be able to see the memory accounting statistics of each cgroup.

Comment: I see -- it looks like I was using "Hide user threads" by default, and thought my screenshot was hiding them while instead it was unhiding them.  After making sure threads were hidden, it looks like gnome is now one line, but there are still dozens of chrome entries. At the very least chrome has its own system monitor so I can use that to troubleshoot low memory issues.

Thanks for the recommendation on `systemd-cgtop`. I'll take a look at that!f